# EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Moustafa\.vscode\extensions\.obsolete'

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code

When i try to install extentions on vscode on my windows 10 machine the installation fails and asks me to install it manually, when i do so another error appears stating:

EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Moustafa.vscode\extensions.obsolete'

I've searched a lot on the web and i didn't find the solution to this problem nor did i find someone posting a similar issue, after searching i fond that the extentions are installed on .vscode the default extentions are there and somehow vscode doesn't have the authorisation to install extentions there.

Answer (score 2):

After searching everywhere on the web for a solution, i didn't find anything so i tried tracing the error log i found that the vscode didn't have permission to access the .obsolete file situated in extensions folder, i didn't know what this file was for so i deleted it and the extensions started working for me.